# Ef Core One-To-Many with join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have two models which both have a collection of the same third model.
Ef Core 5 now creates a foreign key for both models on the collection model but is there a way to let it generate a join table for each relationship without explicitly having a model for the join table?

My Models:

```cs
public class Model1 {
    // ...
    public List<Model3> collection;
}

public class Model2 {
    // ...
    public List<Model3> collection;
}

public class Model3 {
    // ...
}
```

I want the db to look something like this:

Table: Model1

Table: Model2

Table: Model3

Table: Model3Model1 (JoinTable)

- Model3Id
- Model1Id

Table: Model3Model2 (JoinTable)

- Model3Id
- Model2Id

But I don't want explicit Types for those join tables.
I know that EFCore is able to infer those join tables for many-to-many relationship so I was wondering if there is a way to do this for one-to-many as well.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships ? Particularly the sections `Joining relationships configuration` and `Indirect many-to-many relationships`?

Comment: The `UsingEntity()` method seems to be only available for many-to-many and the approach in `Indirect many-to-many relationships` uses an explicit join model which is what I'm trying to avoid. If this should be the only way then I'd rather have the foreign keys on the third model instead.

Comment: db first or code first?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing something like what DevExpress's GUI database designer does. When you programmatically select the connector type "Many to Many" between two tables, the designer generates a db join table, but in code simply displays as `Collection` type on both sides of the relationship. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @NateW I want a one to many but instead of having foreign keys on model3, which EF Core does by default, I want it to generate a join table like it does for many to many relation ships.

Comment: @Vernou code first.

Comment: You know, I think there's something you're asking about that I'm not understanding. You're asking about relating together two tables that are not a many-to-many using a join table? The way my brain is hearing your question, you're asking if you can get EF to do a many-to-many thing on a one-to-many relationship. I can't get into the brainspace to see why you're asking that.

Comment: @ErikSimon No, you cannot have a joining table for one-to-many relationship. Because that's not how entity-relations work. Does your `Model3` contains any properties other than a primary key (Id)? Could you share the actual models?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The best compromise is private properties in Model3 like :

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Model1> Model1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model2> Model2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model3> Model3 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Model3>()
            .HasMany<Model1>("Collection1")
            .WithMany(m1 => m1.Collection)
            .UsingEntity(j => {
                j.ToTable("Model3Model1");
                j.Property("Collection1Id").HasColumnName("Model3Id");
                j.Property("CollectionId").HasColumnName("Model1Id");
            });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Model3>()
            .HasMany<Model2>("Collection2")
            .WithMany(m2 => m2.Collection)
            .UsingEntity(j => {
                j.ToTable("Model3Model2");
                j.Property("Collection2Id").HasColumnName("Model3Id");
                j.Property("CollectionId").HasColumnName("Model2Id");
            });
    }
}

public class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Model3> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Model3> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Model3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private List<Model1> Collection1 { get; set; }
    private List<Model2> Collection2 { get; set; }
}
```

The generated join entity has a navigation property, where the name is  + "Id". The tricky part is to set the desired column name.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want any foreign key on Model 3 itself.
I want two join tables like in a many to many relationship

Comment: I have edited my answer, but it isn't perfect solution.

Comment: @vernou can we get a row from Model3Model1 table without getting model1 ?

Comment: @Hadas, Yes, if model1 isn't included in the query, it isn't loaded. Example to select the entity model3 (table Model3Model1) and load only the entity model2 (table Model3Model2) : `db.Model3.Include(m => m.Collection1).Where(...)`